# Saving Arduino output to a text file in append mode

Tags: processing-lang

I used the code below to save output from an Arduino Uno to a text file.

The problem is whenever I run the code the old data in the text file is deleted.

I don't want the old data to be deleted, what should I change?

```
import processing.serial.*;
Serial mySerial;
PrintWriter output;
void setup() {
   mySerial = new Serial( this, Serial.list()[0], 9600 );
   output = createWriter( "data.txt" );
}
void draw() {
    if (mySerial.available() > 0 ) {
         String value = mySerial.readString();
         if ( value != null ) {
              output.println( value );
         }
    }
}

void keyPressed() {
    output.flush();  // Writes the remaining data to the file
    output.close();  // Finishes the file
    exit();  // Stops the program
}
```

Comment: [See this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17013103/2065121) for an example.

Comment: I think the problem is with your file name it's the same every time as the same-named file with the same extension can not be stored. To solve you can add a variable before your file name that increments every time so your file name gets changed every time and you can store that variable in EEPROM for further use.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to append to a text file.

1. You can either read the entire file in a temporary variable, then append the new data to it and then write to file.
2. you can implement using printWriter instead like mentioned here:
   https://processing.org/discourse/beta/num_1267767630.html

Let me know if it works.